# Because of fixed header modal box is not working in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-modal

i have a fixed header which uses a bootstrap class "navbar-fixed-top" on my page. A search icon on click of which i have a modal box.This modal box is not working but when i remove the class "navbar-fixed-top", the modal box is working. I'm not able to fix the issue, please someone help